# Ensure my facebook post written in german is not auto-translated when displayed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

On my Facebook page for learning German I am creating short posts written in german for encouraging people to learn the language. But facebook auto-translates the posts when it displays them on other users' news feeds, which defeats the purpose of the posts.

I can post images with text on them instead, but that probably prevents facebook's algorithms from suggesting the posts to users interested in foreign languages, and probably just shows them to random users or users that already follow my page.

Is there a way to write the posts in a way that the text does not get auto-translated, such as adding quotes or writing the text in both english and german, or some other formatting ? Is there a checkbox when posting that disables the auto-translating ?